# Difference between SimpleDateFormat.setTimeZone() and Calendar.setTimeZone()

Tags: java, calendar, simpledateformat

What is the difference between 
    SimpleDateFormat.setTimeZone() and 
    Calendar.setTimeZone()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` will use the specified timezone during formatting, while `Calendar` will just consider the given timezone as that in which the respective date/time are specified. The Calendar's timezone will be converted into the SimpleDateFormat's timezone when formatting the Calendar instance.

Answer (score 2):

Both of these methods do exactly the same thing.

```
SimpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone zone)
```

is essentially a method inherited from java.text.DateFormat. When

```
DateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone zone)
```

is called, it will run

```
 getCalendar().setTimeZone(TimeZone zone)
```

which is the exact same thing as

```
Calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone zone)
```

They are both calling the same method which would set the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeZone is method defined in DateFormat class which internally holds a Calendar object. So it modified Calender object and set's it TimeZone, where as Calendar.setTimeZone set time zone of the existing calender...

Both of these methods are instance methods..